# How to find extracted Zip files and their folder in mac

Tags: macos, zip, deduplication

How can i list all zip files and their extracted folders in order to remove one of them, i downloaded lots of zip files in years(like everybody) and extracted them so now they are taking twice as space as they should.

Answer (score 0):

From the Terminal.app

```
unzip -l file.zip
```

will list the content of the archive. Other options could be to use `zcat` or `jar`.